# Finding cell using Pygsheets and update cells in the same column

Tags: python, google-sheets, pygsheets

I need to update every week a calendar in a Google Sheet with some numbers.
I'm using pygsheets find to find the date, but them I am unable to get the column of that cell so I can update some rows within that column.

```
enter code here
for key in list:
    sheet_name = list[key]
    print(sheet_name)
    # Access the sheet
    sheet = report.worksheet_by_title(sheet_name)
    header = sheet.find(first_day_period)
    print(header)
[<Cell H2 '21 Sep 2020'>]
```

What find returns is a list of cells, but I can't access the column without splitting the result and then use that to find the cell. I was wondering if there was an easier, cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can get the column value by using `Cell.col`.*

#### More Information & Example:

As per the pygsheets documentation on the `Cell` class, there is a `col` value:

> `col`
>
> Column number of the cell.

```
import pygsheets

gc = pygsheets.authorize()
ss = gc.open_by_key('sheet-id')
sheet = ss.worksheet_by_title(sheet_name)
header = sheet.find(first_day_period)

print(header[0].col)
```

Under the assumption that the value contained within `first_day_period` is in cell `I1`, the console output will be:

```
9
```

#### References:

- [Cell - pygsheets 1.1 documentation](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cell.html#pygsheets.Cell)

  - [col - Cell - pygsheets 1.1 documentation](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cell.html#pygsheets.Cell.col)

Answer (score 0):

use
`my_cell[0].address.label`

this will yield 'H2' in your case

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).